# Updating Joomla Update Component

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.5, update, joomla-3.6

I have Joomla 3.5.1 and my Joomla! Update Component version is 3.0.0

I know if I want to update to Joomla 3.6.x I have to first update to version 3.6.0

I have tried clearing cache of Joomla! Update. Clearing cache in the Extension Update. Updating all plugins.

But nothing is working. I cant update to 3.6.0

Even my Joomla! Update component cant find newer version, it is stuck at 3.0.0

I have read elsewhere that I need to update the Joomla! Update Component first before updating Joomla.

Anyone has any idea? I need the newest version for security reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to first update Joomla Update component to 3.6.1 by downloading and installing it from this link
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.6.1/com_joomlaupdate-3.6.1.zip

It was suggested during 3.6.1 update from Joomla official GitHub on this link https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/tag/3.6.1